# How to replace blank " " cell to null without quotes in jmeter while reading data from csv in HTTP Request body? data

Tags: jmeter

I have data in csv and somewhere cell value is blank and when I am using this blank value in my HTTP request body data then it is replacing like "", but I want to replace as null without quotes. Please help here.

**PFA snapshots**

**1**

[image: 1]

**2**

[image: 2]

**3**

[image: 3]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it dynamically using i.e. [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) and the following [Groovy code](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black):

```
def body = sampler.getArguments().getArgument(0).getValue().replaceAll('\"\"','null')
sampler.getArguments().removeAllArguments()
sampler.addNonEncodedArgument('', body,'')
sampler.setPostBodyRaw(true)
```

Add JSR223 PreProcessor as a child of the HTTP Request and it will replace blank values with nulls.

Where `sampler` stands for [HTTPSamplerProxy](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/sampler/HTTPSamplerProxy.html) class instance, it provides access to request body, url, headers, cookies, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I will try to implement this and let you know

Comment: Thanks Dmitri for the solution. This also worked for me but I changed my CSV data set config as suggested by Rahul.

Answer (score 0):

The other simple solution to resolve this problem is to use "" in the test data itself.

Check the below screenshots :-

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I will try to implement this and let you know

Comment: Thanks Rahul. This solution worked for me and I implemented this one as a solution.

Comment: I am glad that I was able to answer your query. I would highly appreciate if you could mark this as an answer. :)